# New relic cli installation failed

Tags: command-line-interface, new-operator, newrelic

installer of NR1 CLI on Windows 11 reports problem with env. path update: ”PATH not updated, new length 1192 > 1024.“

How to solve this? i am getting this issue when i am trying to install the nr1 CLI.

Comment: Take something away from your path? Do you really need all of them?